# What is this peculiarity ? Why should I go for Double Dispatch solution like Visitor Design pattern?

Tags: java, oop, dispatch

Hi I have a basic code peculiarity issue, given below. I get peculiar output when I change the code. The below program gives the correct output as we know that Java does not support Double Dispatch by default. Request you to look into the below code and see the output. After that I modified the code and get weird output.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class SavingAccount {

}

class DematAccount extends SavingAccount {

}

class Bank {

    public void open(SavingAccount act ) {
        System.out.println("... Opening Saving Account ...");
    }

    public void open(DematAccount act ) {
        System.out.println("... Opening Demat Account ...");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SavingAccount> actList = new ArrayList<SavingAccount>();

        Bank bank = new Bank();

        actList.add( new SavingAccount());
        actList.add( new DematAccount());

        for( SavingAccount act : actList ) {
            bank.open(act);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the output is given below.
**... Opening Saving Account ...
... Opening Saving Account ...**

Now let me modify the code and see the output below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class SavingAccount {

    public void open() {
        System.out.println("... Opened Saving Account Successfully ...");
    }

}

class DematAccount extends SavingAccount {

    public void open() {
        System.out.println("... Opened Demat Account Successfully ...");
    }
}

class Bank {

    public void open(SavingAccount act ) {
        System.out.println("... Opening Saving Account ...");
        act.open();
    }

    public void open(DematAccount act ) {
        System.out.println("... Opening Demat Account ...");
        act.open();
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SavingAccount> actList = new ArrayList<SavingAccount>();

        Bank bank = new Bank();

        actList.add( new SavingAccount());
        actList.add( new DematAccount());

        for( SavingAccount act : actList ) {
            bank.open(act);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the output is
... Opening Saving Account ...
... Opened Saving Account Successfully ...
... Opening Saving Account ...
... Opened Demat Account Successfully ...

Now my question is I am getting the result what I am expecting, why should I go for Visitor pattern, in the above code even if it displays "Saving Account", but it properly executes "Demat Account Code" portion.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You're not using double dispatch / visitor is the problem. From inside `DematAccount` it needs to call a method with `DematAccount` as type. When you call `bank.open(act);` in the loop, you use the `SavingAccount` version because that is the type you have in the loop.

Comment: I am not using visitor pattern, look at first part of the code where it provides different result, but in the second part, I get something else. I will apply visitor pattern if I have problem, but here everything seems to be working fine. My question is why we get some different result.

Comment: That's not really different. It's printing the same "Opening Saving Account" message but then you call a method that is implemented differently and prints either Demat or Saving opened successfully. Method calls are determined at compile time, the implementation of classes at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Java does not have runtime parametric polymorphism (selection of method based on parameter type at runtime).

The compiler will call a subclass method polymorphically on an object so `act.open()` will call **DematAccount**'s implementation if **act** is a **DematAccount**.  However, Java's polymorphism does not work on parameters so `bank.open(act)` will always call `open(SavingAccount)` if **act** is a variable of type **SavingAccount** regardless of its runtime type.

The relevant thing the compiler knows at the callsite is that **act** is a **SavingAccount** and that **bank** has a method **open(SavingAccount)** as the closest contravariant match:

```
for(SavingAccount act : actList ) {
    bank.open(act);
}
```

You could do type-casing with **instanceof** and cast **act** to the subclass to workaround this or you could do that type-casing inside the **Bank** class.

```
for(SavingAccount act : actList ) {
    if (act instanceof DematAccount) {
        bank.open((DematAccount) act);
    } else {
        bank.open(act);
    }
}
```

That's kind of ugly and means coupling this code to all kinds of accounts and changing it every time they change.

Changing it inside **Bank** os better since **Bank** has already taken on the responsibility of knowing all **SavingAccount** subclasses.

```
class Bank {

    public void open(SavingAccount act ) {
        if (act instanceof DematAccount) {
            open((DematAccount) act);
        } else {
            System.out.println("... Opening Saving Account ...");
            act.open();
        }
    }

    public void open(DematAccount act ) {
        System.out.println("... Opening Demat Account ...");
        act.open();
    }
}
```

In this case where **Bank** only differs in the console output you could easily move that console output to **SavingAccount** and **DematAccount** and remove **open(DematAccount)** from **Bank**.

Comment: Hi Alain, if that is the case then how come it is calling the runtime type in the "act.open()" method ?

Comment: @Sambit ah.  That's because Java's calls are polymorphic on objects.  `act.open()` can call the subclass method because the runtime has the object to call it on, but `bank.open(act)` can't call the method taking a subclass parameter because **bank** is the object on which polymorphism is decided not **act** and **bank** has an **open()** method for **SavingAccount** so that is what has to be called.